# Comodo firewall exception not working?

Tags: firewall, home-networking, comodo-firewall

I'm very confused. I'm using Comodo Internet Security as a firewall and it is blocking requests from my mobile phone browser to my local webserver.

I can see log entries:

```
    Action   Dir  Source         Port    Destination    Port
    Blocked  In   192.168.1.102  53959   192.168.1.100  80
```

But I've added a rule to allow...

[image: Comodo settings]

If I disable Comodo firewall it works, and it's pretty obvious Comodo is actually blocking something because of the logs... **I'm lost here and appreciate any guidance!**

## Tried based on IP address..

(other tabs allow "any" for that rule)

[image: Based on source address alone]

## still not working :(

[image: All blocked]

Comment: What's on the other tabs of the firewall rule?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: I tried entering both the values specified in my question as well as `any` for all other tab options (any source address, any destination address and any source port).

Comment: What if you create a firewall rule that allows all traffic from your phone's IP?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: that also doesn't work...

Comment: Do you have *other* rules that would be blocking this traffic? Can you disable them? Does it work if you create a *single* Allow All rule? Does the program let you determine which order the rules are evaluated in, in which case your allow rule needs to be at the top?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: regarding determination which rule fires, i can let it add a log entry but can't find another way to evaluate this. There are no other `block` rules except for *mac to mac ICMP* traffic.

Comment: Then again, removing the rule entirely also yields a log entry...

Comment: good find. Sounds like something's wrong with the software. You may want to try an uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: I just found that application rules *overrule* global rules (which from a specificity perspective makes sense) and that the `system` application has a `global block` rule... Don't know what exactly is the purpose of this and how this should be configured else then changing the `custom` **ruleset** that is applied..

Comment: Ok, adding the rule to that application ruleset works :)

Comment: Sounds like you have an answer worth posting!

Comment: Seems like your third comment led to the answer :)

Comment: I'll let you post the answer since you have the software in front of you and can describe it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application rules` overrule `global rules` and there was a rule tied to the `System` application which was handling these requests.